# Contributing to a unsolved problem and writing a paper about it

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing, collatz-conjecture, cellular-automata

How do I write a paper on the Collatz Conjecture without fooling or making an ass out of myself? Im not affiliated to any University at the moment (my past Uni was like 20 years ago, but I didnt fullfill my studies). I am afraid I won't be taken seriously if I write my paper in a not so good formal matter even though I have the description in figures and notes and such.

I think I have a nice approach to atleast make a serious attempt on solving the Collatz C. but I can only give a description of the Automaton that generates configurations of any Collatz-sequence. I think someone with a professional or very good knowledge in Graph Theory can turn my description into a rigorous proof, disproof or determine wether it is undecidable or not. I have a feeling that determining wether it is decidable will also solve the conjecture at an instant, because it might turn into a proof right there. It might take a year or more than a year to write my paper, but now when I do have some ideas I am eager to start writing it quite soon. I know there are other threads on this subject, but writing my paper is specific to Collatz Conjecture, Binary numbers, Cellular Automata, Lattices, Graph Theory (I have little knowledge of) and a little bit of Number Theory (and perhaps Set Theory).

Just want some easy directions and hints before I start writing my paper.
Thanks

Comment: As far as I understand, you do not have a "rigorous proof" at the moment. So my advice is: don't write up a result before you made sure that you have the proof. Based on your own estimation, the process can take a whole year. Imagine if you realize that there is a major gap halfway into the work. That can be half a year wasted, that you could have easily avoided. 
I myself never started writing up a paper before having verified practically every detail of the proof.

Comment: What if it is not a proof, but I want to contribute to the field so others maybe can construct a proof, or is it not the way it is done?

Comment: No, usually it is not. You should first of all think it through. And if you can check at least the major details, and you are still convinced that the strategy makes sense, then you should try to work out the technical problems yourself. If you get stuck, you can ask for help from an expert. But you should be able to present a reasonable sketch of the proof, and convince that person that it is worth the effort. Actually, this forum we have here is also a good place to share ideas (or better yet, math overflow), but again, you need to have a reasonable strategy.

Comment: Two remarks: The Collatz conjecture is infamous for attracting many, *many* amateur mathematicians resulting in many, *many* failed attempts at proofs, many of which have been committed to paper. Some papers present interesting ideas, but by far, most I've seen fail at a very basic level, and to this day little progress has been made. Unless you present some new ideas that have been rigorously verified, and you find the support of a professional mathematician (both could be done here on MSE), you have little chance of being taken seriously by the mathematical community at large...

Comment: ...so I suggest you rigorously make your ideas precise, and share them with professional mathematicians to be scrutinized, for example on this forum.

Comment: Second: As the Collatz conjecture remains so far from a proof after so much time spent on it by so many people, even proving an interesting fact about it (rigorously!)  is worth a publication. Say you manage to prove that *if* the Collatz function has a loop, *then* this loop must be at least [some large number] long. Or that the conjecture is equivalent to some other well-known conjecture (abc?). Just to give some examples. A full proof from out of nowhere is aiming very, very high at this point, and is not often the way mathematicians establish such 'big' results.

Comment: So in reply to your comment; sharing ideas and building on the ideas and results of others *is* often the way mathematics is done. But to publish ideas and results, they must be *rigorously* established, and interesting to others.

Comment: Thank you all for the generous insights. I have a hard time explaining my ideas because I previously opened a thread where I shared my idea and it got closed (voted to close). So I don't want to share the general idea, but I can try and wrap elements of the idea into definite small problems. Maybe thats easier.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Cloney, Goles & Vichniac (1987)](http://www.complex-systems.com/abstracts/v01_i02_a05/) and [German (2004)](http://wolframscience.com/conference/2004/presentations/material/adriangerman.pdf) as examples of articles that say something interesting about the Collatz Conjecture without claiming to prove or disprove it.  The two articles will likely be of interest anyway as they use cellular automata.  They are also indicative of the kind of standards that may be expected, even for journals such as [Complex Systems](http://www.complex-systems.com/) or [Experimental Mathematics](https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/uexm20) that are receptive to research that is a mixture of proved results and experiments.